# Rails 4 Tests running in "development" environment by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

We are porting a Rails 3 project to Rails 4.  Our tests run fine under Rails 3, environment is correctly defaulted to test.  However, when I switch over to my Rails 4 project and run the tests the same way...

```
rake test:controllers
```

My tests are running under development environment, wipes my dev db and output goes to development.log.  I can not figure out the difference.

In my test_helper.rb I have this line...

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
```

I've even tried...

```
Rails.env = "test"
```

and that does not work either.

Strange thing is, I have these puts in my test...

```
puts "#{__method__} Rails.env:       #{Rails.env}"
puts "#{__method__} ENV[RAILS_ENV]:  #{ENV["RAILS_ENV"]}"
```

and they both correctly show that I am in the "test" environment.

If I prefix RAILS_ENV=test before the rake test:controllers, all is well, but I should not have to do that.

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked your system's environment variables? Perhaps you have RAILS_ENV set to development in your shell.

Comment: That would make me think that Rails 3 project would also run in dev mode though?

Comment: Yeah, but you might as well check.

Comment: Have you also looked at `config/database.yml`?

Comment: You may have your testing environment configured to use your development database.

Comment: Unfortunately I have Blaine.  Same code as my rails 3 project, test db block in database.yml is same.  Rails 3 runs fine, Rails 4 does not.  Thanks

Comment: Well, I'm afraid you're going to have to do some more digging, sir. I'm willing to bet a fresh rails 3 project and a fresh rails 4 project wouldn't have this problem, indicating that the problem most likely lies somewhere in your code.